# React-native release build error on iOS: ld: library not found for -lReact

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

Estoy haciendo un build con [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native) en *Xcode* con el esquema de *Release* y me da el siguiente error:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-qwfopvasfnhysedskapbaefsdwer/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/React'
>       ld: library not found for -lReact
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Si intento añadir `libReact.a` en la sección de Link Binary With Libraries en Build Phases no puedo encontrar la librería en mi espacio de trabajo.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Please translate your question, this is the spanish version of SO

Comment: Otherwise your question will be closed

Comment: Ya está, disculpa no me había dado cuenta @Alfredo

Comment: prueba con react-native link

Answer (score 0):

¿Chequeaste de tener todas las dependencias instaladas?

Es decir, correr `npm install` o `yarn` en el directorio principal de tu proyecto.